# React Native button release listener

Tags: react-native, button

I am writing a chat with audio messages. And I want to do something like in Whatsapp or other messengers. When user holds the button - program is recording the voice, when he releases - it stops and sends the message.

My question is how can I use Touchableopacity or Button and listen release event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start recording in [onPressIn prop of TouchableOpacity](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#onpressin) and and stop it in [onPressOut prop of TouchableOpacity](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#onpressout)

Answer (score 4):

The `TouchableOpacity` component has a prop called [`onPressOut`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#onpressout)in which you can pass a function to execute when the user releases the button.